# How to instantiate object with sub-objects in Express using Async?

Tags: express

I'm trying to instantiate an object, `user`, composed of sub-objects (`authData`, `nameData`, and `emailData`), and I've now got it to work synchronously. Just as an exercise, I also wanted to try to implement this using `async`, but I don't know the right syntax to do this. Can anyone help me get the `async` call working right?

Here's my model, `user.js`:

```
const titleEnum = ['Dr.', 'Mr.', 'Ms.', 'Mrs.', 'None'];
const suffixEnum = ['Jr.', 'Sr.','II','III','IV','V', 'Esq'];
const recoveryEnum = ['Recovery', 'Normal'];
const commEnum = ['Comm','Backup'];

var AuthSchema = new Schema (
    {
        dateEffective: {type: Date},
        username: {type: String, required: true, max: 20, trim: true, lowercase: true},
        password: {type: String, required: true, max: 20}
    }
)

var NameSchema = new Schema (
    {
        title: {type: String, enum: titleEnum},
        firstName: {type: String, required: true, max: 25, trim: true, uppercase: true},
        middleName: {type: String, required: true, max: 25, trim: true, uppercase: true},
        familyName: {type: String, required: true, max: 25, trim: true, uppercase: true},
        suffix: {type: String, enum: suffixEnum}
        // suffix: {type: String, max: 8, trim: true, uppercase: true}
    }
)

var EmailSchema = new Schema (
    {
        emailAddress: {type: String, required: true, max: 25, trim: true, lowercase: true},
        recoveryType: {type: String, enum: recoveryEnum, default: "Normal"},
        commType: {type: String, enum: commEnum, default: 'Comm'}
    }
)

var UserSchema = new Schema(
    {
        authData: [AuthSchema],
        nameData: [NameSchema],
        emailData: [EmailSchema]
}
)

module.exports = {
    Auth: mongoose.model('Auth', AuthSchema),
    Name: mongoose.model('Name', NameSchema),
    Email: mongoose.model('Email', EmailSchema),
    User: mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)
}
```

Just below is the synchronous callback function on the route to create a new user. This code works fine now, but as a learning exercise I'd like to implement it using `async.parallel`:

```
var User = require('../models/user'),
    Auth = User.Auth,
    Name = User.Name,
    Email= User.Email,
    UserObj = User.User;

exports.user_create_get = function(req, res, next) {
    var authObj = new Auth({
        dateEffective: moment(Date.now(),"YYYY MM DD").format("YYYY MM DD"),
        username: '',
        password: ''
    });
    var nameObj = new Name({
        title: '',
        firstName: '',
        middleName: '',
        lastName: '',
        suffix: ''
    });
    var emailObj = new Email({
        emailAddress: '',
        recoveryType: '',
        commType: ''
    });

    var user = new UserObj({
        authData: [authObj],
        nameData: [nameObj],
        emailData: [emailObj]
    });
    res.json(user);
}
```

Here's my attempt at implementing the code above using `async.parallel`. (After the `res.json` call, the code below does not populate/render/show any of the fields in the sub-objects, and doesn't even generate any `_id` fields for those sub-objects. There is an `_id` field for the parent object, but just empty arrays -- length 1, with `null` entries -- for the sub-objects).

```
var User = require('../models/user'),
    Auth = User.Auth,
    Name = User.Name,
    Email= User.Email,
    UserObj = User.User;

exports.user_create_get = function(req, res, next) {
    async.parallel({
        auth: function(callback){
            var authObj = new Auth({
                dateEffective: moment(Date.now,"YYYY MM DD").format("YYYY MM DD"),
                username: '',
                password: ''
            })
            callback(this.auth);
        },
        name: function(callback){
            var nameObj = new Name({
                title: '',
                firstName: '',
                middleName: '',
                familyName: '',
                suffix: ''
            });
            callback(this.name);
        },
        email: function(callback){
            var emailObj = new Email({
                emailAddress: '',
                recoveryType: '',
                commType: ''
            })
            callback(this.email);
        }
    }, function(err, result){
        if (err) {return next(err);}
        var user = new UserObj({
            authData: [result.auth],
            nameData: [result.name],
            emailData: [result.email]
        })
        res.json(user);
    })
};
```

Note: I tried using syntax' such as `callback(result.auth.authObj)`, `callback(result.authObj)`, but none of these worked either:

Many thanks in advance if anyone can please provide ideas how to make `async` work in this case!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 'callback(this.auth)', 'callback(this.name)', 'callback(this.email)', etc., I needed to use 'callback(null, authObj)', 'callback(null, nameObj)', 'callback(null, emailObj)'.